# website response files are sent to browser in single roundtrip?

Tags: asp.net, browser, web, webserver

I was asked a question in an interview "if a website request is made in browser, its response including html, images, js files are coming to the browser in a single round trip or multiple internal round trips with server?" and interviewer told that it is done through multiple round trips (internally).

However I am not convinced, because wherever I search and i get the answer as a single response. Any help to understand it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside a html file you'll find references to external resources like

```
<img src="{name of image file etc}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[filename of stylesheet]" />
<script src="..." />
```

These are some elements within a html file that trigger multiple requests.

So a request to a web page may *appear* like a single response, it's actually an aggregate response - made up of lots of resource responses, such as stylesheets, images and javascript files.

Comment: So if the references are all local, then it should be a single response right? All from the same web server?

Comment: If there are any references to resources, like images, stylesheets or scripts then the browser will have made multiple requests whilst rendering the web page. 99.9% of web pages reference a resource, so the vast majority of web requests you make via the browser will result in multiple requests being fired and therefore the response will be aggregate.